# CSS Transform Nav Issues

Tags: css, css-transitions

I am trying to get a navigation working for a personal website. I feel like I've got it functioning more or less how I would like it, but I'm running into some issues I was hoping to get help with.

Here's a link to [my JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cs7484a/5BXN8/).

First, I'm not sure what's happening with nav icon after the CSS transform. I'm trying to apply the cursor:pointer property to the X, but it doesn't seem to be taking. What am I doing wrong?

Code for reference:

```
.bt-menu-trigger {
    position: fixed;
    top: 15px;
    right: 20px;
    display: block;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Also, I was having a problem getting the li elements to fade in. I am trying to style this transition using CSS, but am having a hard time getting this to take, also.

Code for reference:

```
.bt-menu ul {
position: fixed;
z-index: 100;
top:30%;
width: 100%;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
list-style: none;
-webkit-transition: background-color 0.3s ease-in-out, visibility 0.3s ease-in-out;
```

-moz-transition: background-color 0.3s ease-in-out, visibility 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: background-color 0.3s ease-in-out, visibility 0.3s ease-in-out;
     -o-transition: background-color 0.3s ease-in-out, visibility 0.3s ease-in-out;
        transition: background-color 0.3s ease-in-out, visibility 0.3s ease-in-out;

}

If I could get some help with this, I would appreciate it.

Thanks all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First issue : 
you X has the `cursor : pointer` , and works fine , it is just overlayed by a div of class `<div class="bt-overlay"></div>`
so the fix will be :

```
.bt-menu-trigger {
    position: fixed;
    top: 15px;
    right: 20px;
    display: block;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index:99;
}
```

Second issue:

Visibility is not a standard , use opacity instead , and it will work fine

here is the fix:

```
.bt-menu ul li {
    padding: 16px 0;
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-transition: background-color 0.3s ease-in-out, opacity 2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: background-color 0.3s ease-in-out, opacity 2s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: background-color 0.3s ease-in-out, opacity 2s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: background-color 0.3s ease-in-out, opacity 2s ease-in-out;
    transition: background-color 0.3s ease-in-out, opacity 2s ease-in-out;
    }
```

Comment: Your fix for the X was perfect. The opacity fix is still not taking though. I've updated the fiddle.

Comment: @user3453790 ok i added the fix for your second issue , and edited my answer , hope this is what you want.

Comment: All I had to do was add the opacity transition to: 

.bt-menu.bt-menu-open ul li

and that did it. I'll update the fiddle. Thanks for your help.